# Getting Perl Tk FileSelect to select directories

Tags: perl, file, tk-toolkit

How do I get Perl Tk FileSelect to only select directories??

I'm trying this:

```
sub desDirectory{
 $dd = $mw->FileSelect();
 $dirPath = $dd->Show;
 $dd->configure(-verify=>['-d']);
}
```

without success.

Answer (score 0):

Would `$mw->chooseDirectory()` help you?

Comment: Yes it would, but how do I append the file name since I'm making multiple files.`sub makeCopies{ while ($count < 5){ print "$fn\n"; open (FN, $fn) or warn "Unable to open file:$!";            copy($fn, $dir) or warn "Unable to copy:$!";               open(FN,">($count)$fn"); $count++; }`

Comment: @user1020372 : I do not get your second question. How is it related to Tk? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry I should be more clear< i made a script that makes several copies of a a single file, like this: chose a file to copy>>chose a directory to save to>>make several copies and place them in the directory the user chose.But i need to append the file names otherwise it just places the copied file with the same name several times, NOT several copies of the file, am I making sense? I'd post my full code but the code formating for comments is terrible

Comment: @user1020372: You're asking how to do filename manipulation in Perl?